# list of actions + てくださる

Tags: grammar, て-form

suppose there is a finite list of actions i want someone to do for me. How would i go about expressing this?
(perhaps naively) I would try say something like:

> 晩御飯を食べてお風呂に入って寝てください

or

> 晩御飯を食べてくださってお風呂に入ってくださって寝てください

What about expressing a finite list of actions that i'd like to try by using てみたい?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「晩御飯{ばんごはん}を食{た}べてお風呂{ふろ}に入{はい}って寝{ね}てください。」

or

> 「晩御飯を食べてくださってお風呂に入ってくださって寝てください。」

As far as grammar, the first sentence wins by a landslide.  It is very awkward to repeat 「～～てくださって」.

Is the first sentence natural-sounding, then? No, it is not; All it is is grammatical.

「寝てください」 sounds pretty impolite; It sounds almost order-like.  It is much better and more natural to say 「休{やす}んでください」 or 「お休みください」.

「食べて」 is also not too polite.  You might want to use 「召{め}し上{あ}がって」 instead.

My point is that you are already using the polite 「ください」 request form.  In doing so, you would need to consider keeping everything within the sentence on the same politeness level.  Thus, without being ridiculously polite, you could say:

> 「晩御飯を召し上がって、お風呂に入って、お休みください。」

**I would (strongly) recommend that you insert 「から」 or 「それから」 right before 「お休みください」 for a better flow**.  Without doing so, you could end up sounding a little blunt.

> What about expressing a finite list of actions that i'd like to try by using てみたい?

Basically, you can use the same sentence structure as your first sentence above, meaning that you should use 「～～てみたい」 **only once at the end**.

For instance, one could say:

> 「日本{にほん}に行{い}ったら、スシをたくさん食{た}べて、原宿{はらじゅく}で買{か}い物{もの}をして、できれば京都{きょうと}にも行っ**てみたい**。」

The speaker is talking about himself here, so using 「食べる」 is completely fine.

Comment: This answer points out that 「食べて」 is not too polite.  I agree wholeheartedly, and would like to note that even experienced speakers will occasionally make this mistake.  DON'T fall into that trap.  The better you get with the language, the less forgiving people will be of simple mistakes like that.